# Create custom language switcher module

Tags: module, language

I would like to customize the language switcher module, that is I would have some different effect, like having name and flags together.
How could I perform it?

EDIT:

Joomla version 3.3.6

template used: SJ plus v1

Answer (score 4):

You can easily create an override of that module from Template Manager, as explained here:

http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager#Creating_Overrides

Just go into the "override" tab and click con "mod_language" on the modules list. You'll get lang switcher overrideable file added to your template's HTML folder (inside a mod_language subfolder). Just browse to that file and edit it directly from your template manager:

http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager#Customisation_View

Once there, it's up to your HTML/CSS skills how much you can modify the module ;).

Comment: do you mean that firstly I need to select a template in template manager? I don't see the "override" tab...

Comment: I've noticed that, for other templates, there is the "override" tabs, but for this template there is no tabs and tree of files is not shown...

Comment: Hmmm... first of all, just to make sure... we're talking about Joomla 3.3, right?

Comment: yes, I've added the info into the post right now :)

Comment: Ok, so then maybe the template was not created properly with all the stuff it needs for the backend... are you sure you can't click on template's name from "Styles" page in Template Manager? The last column to the right should have a link, and clicking on it you should be able to open Template Customization view...

Comment: I can click on it, but I do not show the tree on left, and tabs too are hidden. I put the template name into the post.

Comment: @FrancescoDS - If you're unable to create a template override via the Template Manager, you can do it manually as explained [here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)